# Combinatorics question simple

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 100 people in a tennis tournament. I want to find the total number of combinations of matches of doubles. So P1&P2 on Team 1 vs P97&P98 on Team 2 count as ONE combination of matches of doubles. How many total of these are there?

I am thinking there are $\binom{100}{2}$ for the first team and $\binom{98}{2}$ for the second team. However, simply multiplying these together give an overcount. I have to divide by $2!$ since I can choose either the first or second team in any order? So final answer is $\frac{\binom{100}{2}\binom{98}{2}}{2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: if you count $P1&P2$ on Team $1$ and $P97&P98$ on Team $2$ the same as $P97&P98$ on Team $1$ and $P1&P2$ on Team $2$. i.e there is no order for the teams

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.  You initially counted each match twice, by taking the teams in two different orders.  Dividing by two corrected for that.